# Go to File not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with Visual Studio Code. When I Press `Ctrl+P` I get a message saying:

`[UriError]: Scheme is missing: {scheme: "", authority: "", path: "undefined", query: "", fragment: ""}`, then nothing happens.

I have tried restarting the computer and Code, adding proxy settings, reinstalling Code. But the problem still exists. I started a few days ago, not sure if it was in combination with an upgrade.

I have checked that `ctrl+p` is assigned to the Go to File shortcut.

Comment: i have the same problem here. Ubuntu 17.10 visual studio code 1.28.
That are my ext:
DSKWRK.vscode-generate-getter-setter
Angular.ng-template
eamodio.gitlens
eg2.tslint
esbenp.prettier-vscode
johnpapa.Angular2
monokai.theme-monokai-pro-vscode
ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare
rbbit.typescript-hero
robinbentley.sass-indented
shinnn.stylelint
stringham.move-ts
whizkydee.material-palenight-theme

Comment: there is just a official bug https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing and re-cloning the project the error was gone.

Comment: was having the same problem in the same scenario and this worked for me

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the Vim Extension:

- Right click the vim extension in the extensions browser
- Choose "Install Another Version"
- Choose "1.25.2"
- Reload vscode

Credit: @mathtick

Comment: this works for me!

Comment: Here's the relevant issue: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/8832. VSCodeVim users might also be interested to know about [vscode-neovim](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim).

Answer (score 5):

Check your VS keyboard bindings - most probably you assigned another combination with `ctrl+P`, change the other one you find and then it should work - that was the scenario I faced with it

Comment: In my case, somehow it suddenly was added as a vim binding to something. Not sure why as the vim extension was in use for several years.

Answer (score 1):

If your ctrl+p shortcut does not open Go to file search then try ctrl+e VsCode also has this command to go to file search.

Comment: no it just goes up a line something is wrong

Comment: Ah, it is the vim plugin. Just roll back until they fix.

Comment: Also, adding "vim.handleKeys": { "<C-p>": false } to your settings.json seems to do the trick, at least to some extent. Source: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/8594#issuecomment-1720225318